# SignalR - Type or namespace name 'Hub' could not be found

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I am new to the SignalR library. I created a new web project in VS2010, then in Package Manager Console I executed the below command to set up the SignalR packages.

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Aspnet.SignalR -pre

So it downloaded all the necessary files into the application.
----------
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR 1.0.0-rc2'.
Successfully added 'jQuery 1.6.4' to demo.
Successfully added 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS 1.0.0-rc2' to demo.
Successfully added 'Newtonsoft.Json 4.5.11' to demo.
Successfully added 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core 1.0.0-rc2' to demo.
Successfully added 'Owin 1.0' to demo.
Successfully added 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin 1.0.0-rc2' to demo.
Successfully added 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure 1.0.0.0' to demo.
Successfully added 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb 1.0.0-rc2' to demo.
Successfully added 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb 1.0.0-rc2' to demo.
Successfully added 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR 1.0.0-rc2' to demo.
----------
```

Now I added a new class file called `LetsHub.cs`.

In that file I wrote the following code,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;

namespace demo.Hubs
{
  [HubName("chatHub")]
  public class LetsChat : Hub
  {
      public void SendMsg(string Message)
      {
         Clients.All.addMessage(Message);
      }
  }
}
```

I am not able to inherit this `Hub` class.

`Type or Namespace name Hub cound not be found ( are you missing using directive or assemblr reference ? ).`

I am facing the same problem on VS 2012 as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Hub class was moved to a different namespace in  in RC2. please change to Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR

Comment: Can you be a bit more elaborate? What would the asker have to change in his code?

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer doesn't work for me. In my .NET Core 3.1 this is my code:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace SignalRChat.Hubs
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can see it has been 3 years but did you find the solution I really need it right now.

Answer (score 1):

Change `public class LetsChat : Hub` to

```
public class LetsChat : Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hub
```